# Why is my audio so high pitched on garageband?

Tags: garage-band, audio-editing

I recorded some music and downloaded it as a mp4. When I imported it into GarageBand the voices sounded like chipmunks. I checked to see the sample rate and it is at 32 khz. Apparently, that might be the issue. How do I check the track info and change it to 32 khz so the voices sound normal?

Comment: I don't use garageband, so I can't answer your question, but you want the imported audio upsampled to project sample rate, not project sample rate lowered to 32kHz.  Lowering your project sample rate will have a detrimental effect on the quality of every sound in the project.

Comment: @Edward That sounds like an answer.

Comment: I didn't post as an answer because I don't know how to do that in garageband, as I don't use it.  Anyone who does is welcome to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the sample rate was misgauged during conversion. How did you originally record it? What's the original file format, and how did you convert it to mp4?

If you can, go back to your original recording, download it in the most lossless format possible (e.g. wav file). If it's originally a video file, then convert it to an audio file on your computer using a respected audio editor like Audacity (open source) or Goldwave (no affiliation). Then import the audio file into GarageBand.

In future, record audio using a dedicated audio recorder app with flexible export options. The one I use on Android lets me choose various filters, e.g. recording dialogue or music; various quality levels; and various export formats. But there are many good ones. Recording using your phone camera or a notes app or similar stand-ins for the real thing will lead to janky results.

Comment: Might have been some kind of voice recorder/notes/memos app, at 32k.

Comment: @Tetsujin Certainly could have been, but my hypothesis here is that the encoding is borked (rather than that GB just can't read 32khz rates, though that is also a possibility worth investigating).

Comment: (Another way to extract audio from a video file is with the open-source command-line program `ffmpeg` — the Swiss Army knife of media file conversion — as that can do so losslessly, and understands a huge range of formats.)

Comment: "I recorded some music"... great, now where is the wav file? +1